# "Cannot convert relative path .ABC\daemon\8.0 to an absolute file." Configuration error in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

I am having this issue in my mobile app written in kotlin, I recently accidently changed some names and now I am having this configuration gradle problem.

I have searched a lot but was unlucky to find any solution. Certainly, I am very new to the Mobile Apps so don't have any idea what to do now

Comment: Which issue? In which mobile app?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.